# Preventing line breaks in HTML

Tags: html

Is there any way to prevent a line break in HTML?  For example, on one of my web pages the browser put a break after the comma in the number 43,560.  I could remove the comma, but that makes the number harder to read.

I seem to remember old-style HTML has a way to prevent line breaks but it isn't universally supported and isn't legal in stricter varieties like XHTML.

Comment: belongs to stack overflow !

Comment: or belongs in doctype

Comment: The tag you were looking for was the `<NOBR>` tag, but you should use Johannes's answer below.

Comment: http://doctype.com/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use styles to ensure that the browser won't break lines there. CSS has a [white-space](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/CR-CSS21-20070719/text.html#white-space-prop) property which does that. So

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap;">43,560</span>
```

should work.

If you need this more often, you should probably create a CSS class for that, though.